# Converting a .sqlite file to MSSQL format

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to do this, so far I've found a [firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) that converts my .sqlite file to some sort of .sql create script (need some advice on what format this is, is it sqlite, but then what's the difference between this and a .sqlite file?).

I've tried executing it in MySQL and MSSQL and it won't run so I'm guessing it's some kind of sqlite syntax.

Is there anyway I can convert this .sql file so it's in MSSQL syntax to drop into my database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on what you have written, the firefox addon is not your tool. I recommend you go with SQL Server Import and Export wizard (which is found inside your Start->Programs->SQL Server folder). There you can select the source and target databases.

But before you begin you will have to create an ODBC connection to your sqlite database. Please use the [open source driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) to set the ODBC connection string to your sqlite database.

Then in the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard select ".Net Framework data provider for ODBC" as a source database and type in your connection string. You will have to also nominate your target SQL Server database in the next step.

After that the wizard will provide you options to what to import

Comment: Thankyou, I'm going to give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: I could not get the ODBC open source driver to work. It seems like quite an old program, maybe it does not work with SQL Server 2012 and windows 7. If there are no more answers I will mark this as correct. My plan now is to write a parser to convert sqlite sql to MSSQL.

Comment: I think the driver should work. I have installed it once on a Win 7 machine. What could be old is the installer for the driver. Have you tried to run the installer as administrator?

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear, I did manage to get it to install I just couldn't seem to get it setup with my database file.

Comment: you need to create a system DSN. Open ControlPanel->AdministrativeTools->DataSources(ODBC). Then Open System DSN, and click Add. Select SQLite3 ODBC Driver. Then populate fields. In the datasource name type "MySQLIte", then browse to your sqlite file. Leave other settings as they are. Once this is done, you will be able to use the "MySQLite" in the import wizard

Comment: Ah, I guess there's my problem, when I click 'Add' the only two options I have are 'SQL Server' and 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'. I guess that means the driver did not successfully install?

Comment: I don't know. I have a whole lot more. Do you see the driver when you open Drivers tab page? I have like 20 of them. Are you an administrator on your machine?

Comment: Thanks for this, I've made some progress now, I did some re-installing of the driver and SQLite3 appears in the options, I think the last hurdle is I can't figure out what to put in the connection string.